# IBM JRE : validate DOMSource with xsd doesn't work

Tags: java, xsd-validation

The following code works fine in oracle jre but not in ibm ones (try the version 5, 6 and 7). The code just validate some xml against a xsd.

Is it a known bug ? Is there a magic property or feature to set ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xsd = "<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"+
                    "<xsd:element name=\"comment\" type=\"xsd:string\"/>" +
                "</xsd:schema>";
    String xml = "<comment>test</comment>";

    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema( new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsd))); 
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    validator.validate(source);
    System.out.println("ok");
}
```

The exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'comment'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
```

I can bypass this bug, if I transform my document to a String and using a StreamSource. But i'd like to validate the document directly. This example could not be simpler and should work on IBM JRE, isn't it ?

Comment: You might need to call `DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks Andreas, your tip is working. To be honest, i tried the opposite before asking the question. namespaceaware = false. (Because i don't have namespace.) May be you can create an answer and i can validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)`.

This is necessary because you are using an XML Schema, which is namespace based, *even* when there is no namespace url. The Oracle JRE is apparently lenient and supported it without that attribute, while the IBM JRE is a bit more strict, i.e. `<comment>` *without* a namespace (false) and `<comment>` with *no* namespace (true) are considered different.

Change your code to:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```